# How to create toolbar with Activity Indicator in SplitView templete?

Tags: objective-c, uitoolbar, uiactivityindicatorview, ipad

I am new to ipad development. In my application i want to create splitview like the below image.  I made a new splitView application from XCode templet.
How to create toolbar with Activity Indicator in TableViewController like a Mail.app?

Comment: [IMAGE LINK](http://aleyrobotics.com/images/IMG_0447.jpg)

Comment: i found it. [MasterViewController.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to put a `UIActivityIndicatorView` in a `UIToolBar`. You can add it as a subview of the toolbar, or better, create a custom `UIBarButtonItem` using `-initWithCustomView:`.

Comment: How to add UIToolBar to UITableViewController in SplitView templete application?